# Float image and long text css Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to float image and text in the paragraph. But there is some problem when text is long and in one line. It looks fine in the Chrome, but not in the Mozilla Firefox. You can check it [there](http://dabblet.com/gist/c0962b43db5a8e95d639):

In the Chrome it looks as:

[image]

and FireFox:
[image]

How can I do it correctly? 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML so we don't need to follow a link to see it. Some people might have a policy of not following links in questions if it's on a site they don't recognise. You're making people go to extra effort to help you, which isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this and it's a silly test data mistake.  If Firefox (and maybe other browsers) doesn't find a logical word break, it has nothing to wrap and therefore it stays on one line.  Add spaces to your long test text and remove white-space: pre from your paragraph.

```
body p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://dabblet.com/gist/9b9e1ca0f2c65c550471

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use:

```
float:left;
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 500px;
```

width: ** The width of the word you want to break in px or % **;